# KendoUI grid - modify data after request

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

is there a way to manipulate(transform) data right after the request to the server or before binding?
I need to make request to the server, transform result data and then bind that data to the kendo grid.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you should use either [`parse`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) in the `schema` definition or in the [`dataBound`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-dataBound) event.

Example in `parse`

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: ..
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        parse: function(data) {
            // Example adding a new field to the received data
            // that computes price as price times quantity.
            $.each(data, function(idx, elem) {
                elem.price = elem.qty * elem.price;
            });
            return data;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, was I going in the wrong direction! Thanks, you have just saved me couple of hours!

Comment: @OnaBai, how would you do that in the `dataBound` event? From what I see in the documentation the only property exposed in the event is the `sender`: The widget instance which fired the event. How can I manipulate the dataSource in the `dataBound` event?